# Javascript Regex - Replace { with nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

i have a little problem and i have no idea what is wrong

```
    var selector_css;
    var sheet= document.styleSheets[0];
    var rules= 'cssRules' in sheet? sheet.cssRules : sheet.rules;
    for (var i= 0; i<rules.length; i++)
    {
        var rule= rules[i];
        var text= 'cssText' in rule? rule.cssText : rule.selectorText+' {'+rule.style.cssText+'}';
        text =  text.replace(/\s/g, '');
        selector_css = text.match(/^(.*?){/gi);
         // selector_css = selector_css.replace(/{/g,'');  // <- dont work ?
        $('body').append('- '+selector_css+' <br />');
    }
```

Everything works fine but when i add

```
selector_css = selector_css.replace(/{/g,'');
```

I dont get a result or an error, but why?
Can somebody help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/beMKY/

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: You have to escape the braces like so: /\{/g

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some special chars like "." need to be escaped:

```
selector_css = selector_css.replace(/\{/g,'');
```

But in this case the problem is that **css_selector** is a object (array) and not a string.
You can apply **`replace`** only to a string!!! Use

```
selector_css = selector_css[0].replace(/\{/g,'');
```

Comment: // only to a string ... sorry, i was blind :) ... Thanks for the fast help!

Comment: Nice, didn't catch that either. :)